# response is not getting from server when we use UrlConnection class for connecting to server in android

Tags: android, url, inputstream, urlconnection

In my android project, I have a problem. (i.e) some times response is not getting from server. I use Urlconnection class for connecting to server.

```
URL myURL = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = myURL.openConnection();

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();



        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
            Log.v("response is .....",
                    "=================Response===================="
                            + sb.toString());

        }

        in.close();
```

Comment: Which web service are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use HTTpURLConnection and after getting stream better to check is that connection is successful i think this may helps you.

```
URL myURL = new URL(url);

    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();

    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
            Log.v("response is .....",
                    "=================Response===================="
                            + sb.toString());
        }
    } else {
        Log.v("response is .....", "Wrong response Code from server :"
                + conn.getResponseCode());

    }
    is.close();
    conn.disconnect();
```